# Problems inserting data into a database table

Tags: android, sql

I have problems when trying to insert data in a table. The code for table creation and inserting is the following:

```
    // Creamos la tabla Montanas
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE montanas ("+
            "_id INTEGER PIMARY KEY, "+
            "nombre TEXT, "+
            "sierra TEXT, "+
            "altitud INTEGER, "+
            "longitud REAL, "+
            "latitud REAL, "+
            "categoria INTEGER, "+
            "url TEXT, "+
            "foto TEXT, "+
            "num_visitas INTEGER, "+
            "fecha LONG, "+
            "valoracion REAL, "+
            "comentario TEXT)");

    // Añadimos montanas
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO montanas VALUES (null, 'Abitigarra', "+
            "'Iturrieta', 1165, 551613.0, 4734431.0, TipoCategoria.CAT1.ordinal(), "+
            "'http://www.mendikat.net/modules.php?name=tracks&id=797', '', 0, "+
            "System.currentTimeMillis(), 0.0, '')");
```

And here is the error I get when executing it:

```
07-21 18:46:16.062: E/SQLiteLog(1485): (1) near "(": syntax error
07-21 18:46:16.073: D/AndroidRuntime(1485): Shutting down VM
07-21 18:46:16.083: W/dalvikvm(1485): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-21 18:46:16.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 18:46:16.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mendiakmendi/com.example.mendiakmendi.ListViewMontanas}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO montanas VALUES (null, 'Abitigarra', 'Iturrieta', 1165, 551613.0, 4734431.0, TipoCategoria.CAT1.ordinal(), 'http://www.mendikat.net/modules.php?name=tracks&id=797', '', 0, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0.0, '')
```

.
.
.

Can you help me, please? I can't see what's the problem.

Comment: this is why i don't understand that people still try to actually write sql. there are tons of libraries that will do that for you and avoid painful syntax typos. (even using basic android classes, using `insert(ContentValues)` would have prevented that issue...)

Comment: you don't want to have `TipoCategoria.CAT1.ordinal()` in the request string. (but the error log already told you that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the decimal point in latitude and longitude, as you have those as Integer's in your table.   http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to put in the result of TipoCategoria.CAT1.ordinal() and not the methodname as string ... so I think you have to change your sql string to:

```
4734431.0," + TipoCategoria.CAT1.ordinal() + "
```

and also

```
"" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  db.execSQL("INSERT INTO montanas VALUES (null, 'Abitigarra', "+
            "'Iturrieta', 1165, 551613.0, 4734431.0, "+TipoCategoria.CAT1.ordinal()+", "+
            "'http://www.mendikat.net/modules.php?name=tracks&id=797', '', 0, "+
            System.currentTimeMillis()+", 0.0, '')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove System.currentTimeMillis() from the quotes...

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO montanas VALUES (null, 'Abitigarra', "+
        "'Iturrieta', 1165, 551613.0, 4734431.0, TipoCategoria.CAT1.ordinal(), "+
        "'http://www.mendikat.net/modules.php?name=tracks&id=797', '', 0, "+
        System.currentTimeMillis()+", 0.0, '')");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is probability when you are creating the table at the _id column you should write INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, you forgot one latter.